# Tokyo Ghoul Re: Anime what part in the manga?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I just finished Tokyo Ghoul: Re manga, and I'd like to know what part of the anime is already covered?

Comment: It covers everything but is rushed and there were chapters that were skipped. If you don't mind that, you can watch it without confusion since you already read the manga.

Comment: Okay actually I was looking forward to the anime because I didn't appreciate the manga. I wanted to watch it to understand the manga better. Based on what you said, it doesn't sound like I'll appreciate it more.

Comment: I apologize if I discouraged you from watching. You can try to, if you want. Personally, I don't like it but that's because of the skipped chapters and it feels rushed to me.

Comment: No worries! I was already skeptical of whichever studio who made the anime based on what I read about root A anime. I'll probably watch it in the future, but not really a priority I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the fourth season, the anime covers all of the manga story (with a gap between seasons 3 and 4, on the other hand).